# Delphi control that could mimic "Add-ons|Extension list" of Firefox?

Tags: delphi, user-interface, firefox, controls

My aim is to update the look of the GUI in my app. Currently my GUI contains a lot of listboxes which are used to edit some objects in an old fashioned way, that is, user double-clicks an item and a dialog is shown to modify the corresponding object.

I think a good modern approach is how Firefox displays the extensions installed (a snapshot below).

My question is about how to build such a GUI in Delphi(win32) easily? Are there any components you use mimicing such behaviour or will I just need to code this from stratch using panels? (IMO a very cumbersome job I'd like to avoid - the selection logic, resizings, etc...)

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do something similar (not exactly) with standard components; TDBCtrlGrid, TSpeedButton,...

[alt text http://img8.imageshack.us/img8/9585/imagen29ox3.png](http://img8.imageshack.us/img8/9585/imagen29ox3.png)

Comment: The image seems no longer available!

Comment: Sorry. It was in a free server and has expired.
I note for next time. :-(

Answer (score 7):

If you're using Delphi 2007 or Delphi 2009, you might be able to do something similar using TCategoryButtons (from the 'Additional' component palette page). Drop it on a form and right click to display the popup menu, and then click "Categories Editor...". Add a category with the resulting dialog, set it's caption, and optionally set up Items it contains. Not exactly the same, but it might do what you need.

You could also use a dialog with a TTreeView (if you have categories of objects) or TListView to emulate the Delphi 2007 Projects->Options dialog. Clicking an item in the TreeView or ListView displays the proper page of a TPageControl to configure the object.

Comment: Thanks, Cesar.

Finally got around to setting up an OpenID so I could answer questions here. <g> Been lurking on occasion, but just for short times.

Comment: This seems the viable choice in D2007 and above. Though unfortunately I don't have it. Thanks.

Comment: It might be nice, in the future, if you included which version of Delphi you were using; it would help people know which solutions might be acceptable. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Using a TFrame for each list item and put them all Aligned Top on a TScrollBox might work. Also see TDBCtrlGrid which does something like that in combination with datasets.

Comment: Thanks Lars, I've gone a similar direction Neftali suggested.

Answer (score 3):

I mostly agree with Lars, but I would use a frame for each item instead of a panel. That would separate into its own file, and you would get easy designtime support for it.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done with existing Delphi controls.

For instance in the *TCustomListBox* control you can create your own **OnDrawItem** event to draw your own list item. You also need to create your own **OnMeasureItem** to change the item height.

In some cases it is very limited, so if you want more freedom you will need to do it from scratch.

Comment: This is exactly what I was avoiding :-) Thanks though!