# Displaying items on the dbctrlgrid without datasource in Delphi

Tags: delphi, user-interface, delphi-xe8

I am trying to display items from a list of objects. I want to display the data in the following format as shown in the picture.

```
type
  TFeedItem = class
  private
    FTitle: string;
    FDescription: string;
    FLink: string;
    FImageUrl: string;
  public
    property Title: string read FTitle;
    property Description: string read FDescription;
    property Link: string read FLink;
    property ImageUrl: string read FImageUrl;
  end;
```

//Code to disply items

```
var
  I: Integer;
  list: TObjectList<TFeedItem>
begin
  for I := 0 to list.count - 1 do
  begin
    // display each item of the list into dbctrlgrid
  end;
end;
```

[image]

A search results the following threads:

Link1: [Delphi control that could mimic "Add-ons|Extension list" of Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513229/delphi-control-that-could-mimic-add-onsextension-list-of-firefox?lq=1)

Link2: [Custom draw ListBox items with a panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662995/custom-draw-listbox-items-with-a-panel?lq=1&lq=1)

As per suggestions, I tried to use dbctrlgrid but I could use it only with database using datasource property assigning to the TFDTable. So the question is, how  can it be done without datasource?

**Edit**: The question was ambiguous. So, I updated it and added a sample structural code.

Comment: There have been a few qs about a  non-db DBCtrlGrid, but on-one seems to know if one exists.  I don't follow your aversion to using a datasource, though - it should be fairly trivial to load the json data into e.g. a TClientDataSet, then populate the a DBCtrlGrid from that.

Comment: Can you use `TFDMemTable`/`TMemoryTable` for this purpose?

Comment: I don't think mixing a firemonkey form in a VCL project is a good idea. But I tried and got to do this one (http://i.imgur.com/rLSdjmc.png?1) . I am looking for a better method.