# Drawing unicode text on listbox canvas is too slow

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-xe8, drawtext, tlistbox

I am trying to display news from a RSS in a listbox using the following format as shown in the image below. The application on the screenshot has been developed in firemonkey by styling the listbox. I need to display the same in my VCL application.

[image]

The requirements of this layout are:

- The news title should be bold text
- The short description should be located at bottom and it should be
  wrapped if it doesn't fit in a single line(as shown in the image);
  font-style should be normal
- There should be an image for each news item

My code so far:

```
procedure TfrmDatePicker.ListBox1DrawItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer;
Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
var
  R: TRect;
begin
  ListBox1.Canvas.Font.Color := clBlack;
  ListBox1.Canvas.Font.Style := [fsBold];

  ListBox1.Canvas.Font.Size := 9;

  if Odd(Index) then ListBox1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clWhite
  else ListBox1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBtnFace;

  ListBox1.Canvas.FillRect (Rect);
  ListBox1.Canvas.Pen.Color := clHighlight;

  if(odSelected in State) then
  begin
      ListBox1.Canvas.Font.Color := clHighlightText;
      ListBox1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clHighlight;
      ListBox1.Canvas.Rectangle(Rect.Left, Rect.Top, Rect.Right, Rect.Bottom);
      if(odFocused in State) then DrawFocusRect(ListBox1.Canvas.Handle, Rect);
  end;

  ImageList1.Draw(ListBox1.Canvas, Rect.Left + 2,
          Rect.top + (ListBox1.ItemHeight - ImageList1.Height) div 2, Index, true);


  ListBox1.Canvas.TextOut(Rect.Left + 70, Rect.Top + 4, 'कान्तिपुर समाचारआजकोपत्रिकामाकेहिछैन');

  ListBox1.Canvas.Font.Style := ListBox1.Canvas.Font.Style - [fsBold];

  R := Rect;
  R.Left := R.Left + 70;
  R.Top := R.Top + 32;
  R.Height := 30;

  DrawText(ListBox1.Canvas.Handle, PChar(ss), Length(ss), R, DT_LEFT or DT_WORDBREAK or DT_NOPREFIX);
  ListBox1.Canvas.TextOut(Rect.Right - 80, Rect.top + 4, '5 mins ago');
end;
```

Here is the output I am getting:

[image: When items with unicode text inserted]

## Problem

Unicode text drawing is too slow and it flickers too much when the listbox is scrolled or the form is resized.

**Note**

- The font has been set to **@Microsoft NeoGothic**
- Itemheight =70; style = ownerdrawfixed
- There is no problem in drawing the same unicode text in the
  firemonkey application posted in the first screenshot.
- The code posted above works pretty fine for normal English text and
  there is no flicker at all. The problem exists only for Unicode text.

**Update:**
It seems the problem is in **DT_WORDBREAK** flag of **DrawText** method. Whenever I remove this flag, there is significant improvement in the drawing the text though the flickers are visible.

**Sample Unicoide Text**

तिम्रो त्यो बोलि ले मलाई बोलायो मिठो तिम्रो त्यो मुस्कान मा मलाई झुलायो झुलाओ ह्स्द्जिः स ह्स्ध्फद्ज द्श्जड्स  हस फग स्द्फ़ ग स्द्फ्ग फस ग्स्द्फ़ ग्दस्फ्ग द्स्फग्द तिम्रो त्यो बोलि ले मलाई बोलायो मिठो तिम्रो त्यो मुस्कान मा मलाई स ह्स्ध्फद्ज द्श्जड्स  हस फग स्द्फ़ ग स्द्फ्ग फस ग्स्द्फ़ ग्दस्फ्ग द्स्फग्द

Comment: I'm confused why you're building a VCL application separate from an FMX application. I'm curious why you would need to do so? Is this just for testing?

Comment: @JerryDodge Actually, I am writing a VCL application having multiple features. News reader is one of them is only left to be implemented.  I tried to search for custom drawing that would display the all the important part. The first attempt is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33057500/displaying-items-on-the-dbctrlgrid-without-datasource-in-delphi but I couldn't get the proper answer. Mixing firemonkey for this single module isn't a good idea, i guess.

Comment: Well my point was, if you're writing this in Firemonkey in the first place, I'm assuming you did so to be multi-platform. Well, Windows is one of the supported platforms. Why not keep just one code-base?

Comment: I'm writing this application only for windows using VCL. The firemonkey screenshot you saw was actually a test application. I was playing with listbox styling , nothing else.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense then. I was under the assumption you were building both an FMX and VCL version of the same thing.

Comment: did you try VirtualTreeView in List-Report mode ? did you try DoubleBuffered := true on the form and/or listbox ?

Comment: I have updated the question again. @Arioch'The I tried DoubleBuffered := true but nothing happens. I have never used VirtualTreeView. I would love to solve the problem using listbox. Btw I'm doing some search on your advice as well.

Comment: create a cache bitmap for each item. to solve two problems, speed issue and flickers. the only issue is it consume more memory;

Comment: @milevyo Did you mean for the image drawing? If I remove the **ImageList1.Draw** function from the **DrawItem** event handler, nothing happens. The problem is with drawing unicode text. Please have a look at the update in the question.

Comment: i am thinking in WINAPI. Create a bitmap with CreateBitmap function , do all your drawings on it first. then when an item want to be redrawn, just do BitBlt that bitmap on it; so you have to Textout only once, next paintings will be drawing that bitmap on the canvas.

Comment: take a look at this : https://books.google.dz/books?id=9JzBn4vcUBoC&pg=PA495&lpg=PA495&dq=offscreen+drawing+delphi&source=bl&ots=wzRoSwnrpT&sig=GJwlGuIqcEbunl_FQvirFDUq8kI&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0CDcQ6AEwA2oVChMIsIak-a3FyAIVAgNzCh3UZARz#v=onepage&q=offscreen%20drawing%20delphi&f=false

Comment: @milevyo I'm learning more convenient way to resolve the issue. Once I get something useful, will reply here back.

Comment: @milevyo isn't that exactly what DoubleBuffered does (or at least supposed to do sans bugs) ?

Comment: @Arioch i believe yes. but internally i don't know how it is working, DoubleBuffer for every list item or for listbox itself. that is strange for me that is so slow as he said

Answer (score 0):

If you REALY REALY REALY want to use a standard ListBox for displaying you RSS feed I suggest you use double Buffering. Meaning you draw your stuff on a bitmap in memory and den draw that to you listView. From you Sourcecode i've made a small demo showing you how to do.I doesn't solve all the problems but I belive this is the best you can get with a standard VCL component.

```
unit Unit12;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ImgList;

type
  TForm12 = class(TForm)
    ListBox1: TListBox;
    ImageList1: TImageList;
    procedure ListBox1DrawItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer; Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormResize(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
  private
    MemBitmap: TBitmap;
    OldListBoxWP: TWndMethod;
    procedure NewListBoxWP(var Message: TMessage);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form12: TForm12;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

const
  NewsStr = 'तिम्रो त्यो बोलि ले मलाई बोलायो मिठो तिम्रो त्यो मुस्कान मा मलाई झुलायो झुल' +
    'ाओ ह्स्द्जिः स ह्स्ध्फद्ज द्श्जड्स हस फग स्द्फ़ ग स्द्फ्ग फस ग्स्द्फ़ ग्दस्फ्ग द्स्फग्द तिम्रो त्यो बोलि ले मलाई बोलायो मिठो तिम्रो त्यो मुस्कान मा मलाई स ह्स्ध्फद्ज द्श्जड्स हस फग स्द्फ़ ग स्द्फ्ग फस ग्स्द्फ़ ग्दस्फ्ग द्स्फग्द';

procedure TForm12.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  ListBox1.WindowProc := OldListBoxWP;
  MemBitmap.Free;
end;

procedure TForm12.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  OldListBoxWP := ListBox1.WindowProc;
  ListBox1.WindowProc := NewListBoxWP;
  MemBitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  MemBitmap.SetSize(Width, Height);

  ListBox1.Items.BeginUpdate;
  for i := 0 to 10 do
    ListBox1.Items.Add(NewsStr);
  ListBox1.Items.EndUpdate;
end;

procedure TForm12.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MemBitmap.SetSize(Width, Height);
end;

procedure TForm12.ListBox1DrawItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer; Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
var
  R: TRect;
begin
  MemBitmap.Canvas.Font.Color := clBlack;
  MemBitmap.Canvas.Font.Style := [fsBold];

  MemBitmap.Canvas.Font.Size := 9;

  if Odd(Index) then
    MemBitmap.Canvas.Brush.Color := clWhite
  else
    MemBitmap.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBtnFace;

  MemBitmap.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
  MemBitmap.Canvas.Pen.Color := clHighlight;

  if (odSelected in State) then
  begin
    MemBitmap.Canvas.Font.Color := clHighlightText;
    MemBitmap.Canvas.Brush.Color := clHighlight;
    MemBitmap.Canvas.Rectangle(Rect.Left, Rect.Top, Rect.Right, Rect.Bottom);
    if (odFocused in State) then
      DrawFocusRect(MemBitmap.Canvas.Handle, Rect);
  end;

  ImageList1.Draw(MemBitmap.Canvas, Rect.Left + 2, Rect.Top + (ListBox1.ItemHeight - ImageList1.Height) div 2, Index, true);
  MemBitmap.Canvas.TextOut(Rect.Left + 70, Rect.Top + 4, 'कान्तिपुर समाचारआजकोपत्रिकामाकेहिछैन');

  MemBitmap.Canvas.Font.Style := MemBitmap.Canvas.Font.Style - [fsBold];

  R := Rect;
  R.Left := R.Left + 70;
  R.Top := R.Top + 32;
  R.Height := 30;

  DrawText(MemBitmap.Canvas.Handle, PChar(NewsStr), Length(NewsStr), R, DT_LEFT or DT_WORDBREAK or DT_NOPREFIX);
  MemBitmap.Canvas.TextOut(Rect.Right - 80, Rect.Top + 4, '5 mins ago');

  BitBlt(ListBox1.Canvas.Handle, Rect.Left - 1, Rect.Top - 1, Rect.Right - Rect.Left + 2, Rect.Bottom - Rect.Top + 2, MemBitmap.Canvas.Handle, Rect.Left - 1, Rect.Top - 1, SRCCOPY);
end;

procedure TForm12.NewListBoxWP(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  if Message.Msg = WM_ERASEBKGND then
    Message.Result := 0
  else
    OldListBoxWP(Message);
end;

end.
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't solve the issue.  Same problem as before. Are there some other options available other than using the standard listbox?
Btw I tried setting doublebuffered := true for both form and listbox and for only listbox as well.

Comment: I know it didn't solve the problem. I jut said this is the best you can get with a standard listbox.  I see a lot of people talking about **VirtualTreeView** (http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php/controls/virtual-treeview) I haven't testet it my self since I have a license to the components from Developer Express. But VirtualTreeView or TcxGrid are valid alternatives.

Comment: Time for closing this question?

Comment: @JensBorrisholt if to talk on DevEx, then cxTreeList  is closer alternative

However DevEx components are very complex per se. And suddenly not very flexible, I had to patch sources to implement simple sorting year ago...