# Lazy loading listbox items in Delphi

Tags: delphi, lazy-loading, vcl, delphi-xe8, tlistbox

I am trying to parse a RSS feed and load its data into the listbox. The item contents are in the form as follows:

```
type
  TFeedItem = class
  private
    FTitle: string;
    FDescription: string;
    FLink: string;
    FImageUrl: string;
  public
    property Title: string read FTitle;
    property Description: string read FDescription;
    property Link: string read FLink;
    property ImageUrl: string read FImageUrl;
  end;
```

The list is custom drawn and will show all the above fields in each item. Since there are more than 100 feed items, it takes much time to download each ImageUrl and display it on corresponding list item. So I thought to fetch first 10 items first. When the user scrolls to end of the listbox, fetch the next 10 items and so on. Actually I am trying to implement the way Facebook and many other android application displays more data items on scroll to end event.

A google search gives most of the results for android implementation or for windows phones.

Comment: Why not use a virtual list box?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I think you didn't understand the problem correctly.  Let's assume if I download images for each **ImageUrl** which contains the image size of 100kb for 100 items, it will consume more bandwidth and will take more time. So why not download the xml, parse it and display only  the first 10 items? In this way only 10 images will be downloaded and displayed. Once the user scrolls to end, it will download the same xml, parse it but will append next 10 items .i.e. 11-20.

Comment: I think I did understand the problem. Perhaps you don't know what a virtual list box is.

Comment: Err, why does it need to re-download the xml when it needs items 11-20?  Won't they be listed in the XML downloaded for 1-10?

Comment: @MartynA Yes, you're right.

Comment: Anyway, a priori I'd look at the source code for TListBox and try and figure out how to tap into its message-processing to catch when it draws the last item highlighted, then post myself a message to retrieve the next group of items.  Of course, there may be a much simpler way ...

Comment: It's the same code I posted in my previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33149592/drawing-unicode-text-on-listbox-canvas-is-too-slow. Do you want me to update the question and write something more?

Comment: Hmmm.. So what is your question? Is it what your fellow programmers think about lazy-loading? Or, have you already made up your mind and want to know how to implement? What is it that you stumble on?. @MartynA `TListBox.TopItem` tells the index of the top item. If one knows how many items are visible, it's pure arithmetic to know how far it is to the end

Comment: @TomBrunberg:  Indeed, but I was wondering how to detect that the selection in the listbox has reached the last item, by whatever means, as a mean of triggering a "top up" of the list contents.  Personally, I'd just stick the data in a ClientDataSet and top that up once it scrolls the the end.

Comment: You know that you need to update when the virtual list box asks for more data

Comment: @TomBrunberg I have no idea what it is exactly named. I just googled, read some posts and found the term 'lazy loading' was used for my question. Btw I am a student.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, the listbox needs to be updated. I need to get notified  when user scrols to end of listbox so that I can download next set of images and append it to the last item of the listbox.

Comment: Lazy loading is a good term of what you described. But I asked you, what is your question? Expressed in one sentence, ending in a question mark. I wish all success in your studies!

Comment: @TomBrunberg Let's say, How to get notified when user scrolls to end of listbox? Something like an event handler? Thanks Btw.

Comment: Use the listbox in virtual mode by setting Style property to  lbVirtual. The listbox will fire `OnData` event when user scrolls so new items becomes visible. If the requested item index is close to the end of what you have in memory, you know you need to download more data.

Comment: @TomBrunberg: In a virtual listbox, its `Count` property can be set ahead of time. There is no difference between displaying 100 items vs 1000 items. So I would set the `Count` to the total number of items in the feed, and cache the XML details somewhere. In the `OnData`/`OnDrawItem` event, return/display the cached text as needed. If the item's image has not been downloaded yet, start a background task to download it (throttling the number of active downloads running at a time). When finished, update the cache and invalidate the item so it can redraw with the cached image.

Comment: @RabiJayasawal: the only way to *accurately* detect scrolling activity is to subclass the listbox and handle its [`WM_VSCROLL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787577(v=vs.85).aspx) message directly.