# Delphi Custom Listview Draw

Tags: delphi, listview, treeview, listbox, components

I am looking to make something like IPhone Listbox !

I found someone who provided a download url for this project: but I was to late and the download url does not work anymore.
So I'm asking if killercode the same member on experts-exchange to upload it again if possible and if there is someone who can help me find the right component for this kind of listbox to use in Delphi.

[image]

Comment: Theme can be downloaded: http://weblogs.asp.net/cumpsd/archive/2004/09/01/223996.aspx

Comment: Can't this just be made using a TScrollBox and some TPanels ?

Comment: I think the controls are repeated for every item, but are only visible for the selected item. And likely, the control content is item-aware. A bit like a TDBControlGrid, but different. I would like to write one, but don't have recent Delphi versions this kind of component?

Comment: thanks for the information but i was looking NOT for the thema but for that listbox tht has tpanel with some checkboxes! i know that TDBControlGrid is good choise but i have a Client/server project and when the server connects i want to add the connection into aTpanel and every new connection will have a new tpanel also justlie listview/listbox that adds automatically a new item

Comment: @user794737 TConnection (and all descendant types) is a non-visual component, so what use would such a ListBox have? What is it that you want exactly? Do you want to automatically open a connection when selected in the ListBox, and thus close the previous selected?

Comment: Put the controls in a frame, size the listbox row to match the frame size on select and some fixed size when not selected.

Answer (score 1):

TDbCtrlGrid looks a lot like what you are looking for.

You just define how each row has to look in the form designer, and that is used as some sort of template for each record in your dataset. It shouldn't take more than a couple of minutes to reproduce whatever you have in your screenshot.

[image]

<sub>*This screenshot was found via google and shamelessly posted here..*</sub>

Also, check this question:
[Delphi control that could mimic "Add-ons|Extension list" of Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513229/delphi-control-that-could-mimic-add-onsextension-list-of-firefox)

It's about somebody trying to mimic the FireFox add-on list:

[image]

Comment: Thank you bro for your information but i have already found that topic before i come here but everytime i try to use TDBCtrlGrid with speedbuttons but it does not work since im working in Delphi 2010

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pay for components, [TMS software](http://www.tmssoftware.com) do an iPhone controls pack, which i *think* has a listview.

Comment: i have used tms conponents and the IPhone Controls pack is NOT for delphi i think but for Asp.net :S don't you think?

Comment: TMS's `TAdvSmoothListBox` might be the one you mean?

Comment: Quite possibly advsmoothlistbox.