# Custom TListView or similar with multi-line text items that expands the selected item height to show action buttons

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to find an existing component or code snippet that allows to create a ListView like component similar to the following one:

[image]

Basically it would expand the selected item to show action buttons while also allowing mutli-line text for each item.

Comment: VCL or FMX? An easy way in VCL, which I saw somewhere - here? - a few days ago, is to make each list item a frame. In the frame have the logic for drawing selected, expanding and collapsing, etc. Then create a lot of these in a `TScrollBox` with `alTop` alignment. I wish I could find the original answer... FMX allows you to do similar things too, of course.

Comment: Found it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513229/delphi-control-that-could-mimic-add-onsextension-list-of-firefox/

Comment: Not enough info and it's not a valid question anyway as far as SO is concerned. The question you should be asking is how can I do this and not where can I get this.

Comment: Thanks @DavidM I tried searching before posting the question but wasn't able to find that post.